# If I need to linkage if I have added project to my solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new in C++ development. I created new solution as well as included project (further A), so now I need to add another (external) project (further B) into my solution. Right click on solution -> add existing project.

So, as far as I understood for now if I need to use some functionality of project B in my project A I should say to project A where header files of project B is reside.

So, right click on project A -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional dirs -> put paths to dirs where .h files are. Ok, so now I can use functionality of project B in my project A, by adding `includes`.

Question is - how and when I should go to tab Linker? I saw there also `Additional dirs` tab, but in which case should I to add something there?

Answer (score 0):

You should find out where project B builds it's libraries. Add that directory to Linker/General/Additional Library Dirs, and add the library names themselves (with .lib extension) to Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies.

Also note you might have to make separate adjustments for different project configurations.

Comment: what do you mean `project B builds it's libraties`? Do you mean I should add `x64\Debug\` dir as `Additional lib dirs?

Comment: I assuming the project B builds some libraries which you are trying to link with project A. If that's not the case then ignore the answer.